# Sequential joining of tables in order

Tags: mysql, order-by

Table `albums` has (among other field) field `id`.

Table `photos` has column `id`, field `album` which is a foreign key referring to album `id` and some other fields (which are irrelevant for the question I ask).

So in an album there is several photos (photos in an album are ordered by `id` of a photo).

Now I introduce one more "level of indirection": Bunches. There may be several albums in one bunch.

For this I add fields `bunch` and `seq INT UNSIGNED` into the table `albums`. `bunch` is the ID of the bunch where the album belongs and `seq` is the number of the album in the bunch.

Now the problem:

Let it is given a bunch ID.

I want to make a SELECT query which selects all photos from albums belonging to the given bunch, ordered first by `seq`s of the albums and then by IDs of photos in the album.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why bunches wouldn't be its own table (I think that would make this problem easier), but I'll run with it as is. If I'm understanding the problem correctly, assuming you wanted bunch 1, something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT p.image
FROM photos p
  JOIN album a
    ON p.album = a.id
WHERE a.bunch = 1
ORDER BY a.id, a.seq, p.id
```

Comment: There is table `bunches`. I just haven't said it explicitly

Comment: Gotcha, this will work as is with the design (it worked on a test db I made based on my understanding from your problem). Personally though I would use linking tables, unless an album can only belong to one and only one bunch and a photo to one and only one album.

Comment: What about just `select p.image from photos p natural join albums where bunchid = 1`?